# permission denied on php from command line

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to run a script using crontab, but I have problems making it work even from the command line. The script runs fine from the browser and it creates some excel files in `reports/` folder which is owned by `apache`. The script file is owned by me: `john`.

When I try to run the script from the command line, I get the following warnings, and the excel file doesn't create. I've tryed with the full path, but I get the same results.

This is what I got after I try to run the script from command line

```
public_html]$ php include/tests/mailme.php

PHP Warning:  fopen(reports/4-March.xls): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/john/public_html/PHPExcel/Shared/OLE/PPS/Root.php on line 90

Warning: fopen(reports/4-March.xls): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/john/public_html/PHPExcel/Shared/OLE/PPS/Root.php on line 90
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Can't open reports/4-March.xls. It may be in use or protected.' in /home/john/public_html/PHPExcel/Shared/OLE/PPS/Root.php:93
Stack trace:
#0 /home/john/public_html/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5.php(233):   PHPExcel_Shared_OLE_PPS_Root->save('reports/...')
#1 /home/john/public_html/include/generate_daily_excel.inc(401): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5->save('reports/...')
#2 /home/john/public_html/include/tests/mailme.php(41): generateDailyExcel('04-02-2013')
#3 {main}
 thrown in /home/john/public_html/PHPExcel/Shared/OLE/PPS/Root.php on line 93

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Can't open reports/4-March.xls. It may be in use or protected.' in /home/john/public_html/PHPExcel/Shared/OLE/PPS/Root.php:93
Stack trace:
#0 /home/john/public_html/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5.php(233): PHPExcel_Shared_OLE_PPS_Root->save('reports/...')
#1 /home/john/public_html/include/generate_daily_excel.inc(401): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5->save('reports/...')
#2 /home/john/public_html/include/tests/mailme.php(41): generateDailyExcel('04-02-2013')
#3 {main}
  thrown in /home/john/public_html/PHPExcel/Shared/OLE/PPS/Root.php on line 93
```

I assume that if I change the owner of `reports`, the browser version will not be allowed to save. I'm new to linux and rights.

Answer (score 2):

When you run php code from command line. The script runs with your user permission , not with www-data user permissions.

You should run script as root (not recommend) , or instead change the file permissions:

```
  sudo chown yourUser:www-data file
  sudo chmod 664 file
```

And you should do nearly the same with the directory:

```
  sudo chown yourUser:www-data dir
  sudo chmod 775 dir
```

Comment: I wouldn't particularly recommend running as root, avoid running anything as root unless you have to

Answer (score 1):

The error is laid out very explicitely for you: "failed to open stream: Permission denied". When you are running this from the command line, you are user "john" (I assume from your home path). Does user "john" have permission to write in the reports directory?

What are the permissions of the actual reports directory?

```
ls -al /home/john/public_html/reports
```